# PHP login does not return error message nor proceeds to welcome page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I created a simple login page using mysql and php.

I do not use a register form so I manually added user data to DB i created prior to that.

The form should redirect me to welcome page or display a error message if the login was not successful, but the form just displays a php code (bellow). If nothing else, the form should at least return error message... I checked the php code and it seems fine to me so i do not know what more to do?

I am using Index.php, login.php, session.php, profile.php (welcome page) and logout.php. I am adding all of these here:

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
include('login.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prijava</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="login">
<img src="http://granital.owjej.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/granital1-1-300x75.png" class="logo" alt="" width="300" height="75" />

  <h2>Prijava v sistem</h2>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
   <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="Uporabniško ime" type="text">
   <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Geslo" type="password"><br><br>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Prijava">
   <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

LOGIN.PHP

```
    <?php
session_start();
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $conn     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "owjej_david", "dadadada", "owjej_kalkulator");
        $query    = "SELECT username, password from login where username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt     = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            header("location: profile.php");
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

}
?>
```

LOGOUT.PHP

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(session_destroy()) { 
  header("Location: index.php"); 
}
?>
```

PROFILE.PHP

```
<?php
include('session.php'); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){ 
  header("location: index.php"); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Your Home Page</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="profile">
 <b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
 <b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SESSION.PHP

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "owjej_david", "dadadada", "owjej_kalkulator"); 
session_start();
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user']; 
$query = "SELECT username from login where username = '$user_check'"; 
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql); 
$login_session = $row['username'];
?>
```

I keep getting redirected to a page that contains this php code, so I think something might be wrong with my php code?

[ERROR HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL1ga.png)

Thanks for your help and sorry for a long post.

Comment: You have a stray n after `session_start();n` in your login.php. Enable error_reporting(), and you should see the issue.

Comment: Thanks i fixed that problem but now when i try to log in a new page opens... i think there might be something wrong with my php?

The page contains
**
prepare($query); $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($username, $password); $stmt->store_result(); if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row { $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Profile Page } mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection } ?> **

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Hey, yeah, sorry, just added the screenshot so you can understand easyer :/ I really have no clue as i am a rookie in this :/

Comment: $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "owjej_david", "dadadada", "owjej_kalkulator"); 
    match.  => what is this  "match." doing there ?

Comment: `if(session_destroy())s {` why this is `s`

Comment: You also have mismatched braces in login.php. You need to enable error reporting and take care to consistently indent your code.

Comment: Where? I checked the code multiple times and i cannot see the error :/

Comment: You did notice [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5121495/476) that answers your problems…?

Comment: I did and it works on my localhost. I must take a look at the server settings then.